# PolymerでJSONから:（コロン）付きのキーを持つ値を取り出したい

Tags: json, ajax, polymer

Polymerでcore-ajaxで以下のようなJSONを処理したいと思います。

```
[
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/", 
    "@type": "schema:Event", 
    "schema:description": "イベント説明文", 
    "schema:name": "イベント名"
  }
]
```

しかしPolymerのcore-ajaxを使った以下のようなコードで取得しようとすると、

> Invalid expression syntax: item.schema:name

というエラーが返ってきます。

```
<core-ajax url="http://example.com/json/" handleAs="json" auto response="{{items}}"></core-ajax>
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
    {{item.schema:name}}
</template>
```

XMLであれば\を使うことで取得できる様子なのですが、
http://qiita.com/futosu/items/ad61eb7584dc70ccce76
を参考に試したところ、データを取得することができませんでした。

```
<core-ajax url="http://example.com/json/" handleAs="json" auto response="{{items}}"></core-ajax>
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
    {{item.schema\\:name}}
</template>
```

PolymerでJSONから:（コロン）付きのキーを持つを取得する方法について、
ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.schema:name` で参照しているために起きています。
そのテンプレートについて詳しくないのですが、通常の javascript の記法であれば `item["schema:name"]` でアクセスすることができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
Polymerではその記法でアクセスできない様子で

>Invalid expression syntax: item.['schema:name'] > Error: Unexpected token [

が返ってきました・・・

Comment: `item.['schema:name']` でなくて `item['schema:name']` ではどうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！`item['schema:name']`で取得出来ました。初歩的なTypoですみません・・・